# How can I fetch documents from a collection which contains a certain field using mongo engine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I want to fetch a document from a collection i.e Company which contains a certain field i.e Name.
I have tried the following query but it does not work. Can somebody help me in correcting this query or maybe suggest a different query to get what I need? Thanks

`Company.objects.get(name__isnull=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` operator

```
Python.objects(name__exists=True)
```

Comment: Hi if you are looking for an easy way you can use mong db compass to fetch the data of your choice they have nice UI apllication which makes you easier to get through...!!

Comment: @kushalBaldev why are you telling about compass. I know about compass. OP question regarding the query in python `mongoengine`